# Is there a way to set more than one segue from a segmented control?

Tags: segue, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: enter image strong textdescription here]

I want to make an application with 3 viewcontrollers and changing the viewcontrollers using segments would be convenient due to its size.

The app has segmented control with 3 segments as shown below. I would like to trigger a segue from it once a segment is taped however when i finish ctrl-draging  the second segue from it, the first one gets deleted automatically.

I didnt use tab bar because on the bottom side of the screen i have placed a pickerview and placing a tab bar next to the picker view would be a bad user experience.

Is there a way to solve this using segmented controls?

Answer (score 0):

So you could use storyboard. But also code. You could have an IBAction and IBOutlet connected to your UIViewController. And when the value changes you can Segue to a different VC.

```
@IBAction func selectorViewAct(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch selecterView.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        //first segment is selected. Go to VC
    case 1:
        //second
    case 2:
        //third
    default:
       
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var selecterView: UISegmentedControl!
```

If you need more information just ask. Hope this helped!